# How to add custom link in header in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, header

How to add custom link (on custom module, not at theme) at header in magento 2

Answer (score 1):

Create `default.xml` file in your custom module.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <block class="Vendor_name\Module_name\Block\Link" name="some_link" before="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom link</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">test</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

[image]

it will display in header links

Comment: Could you please post screen-shot where exactly it will show?

Comment: I have updated my answer with screenshot.